# In FTL Advanced Edition, what can be gained from manning sensor or door subsystems?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

The Advanced Edition of FTL includes the ability to man your sensors and door subsystems. Why? What does it accomplish?

Comment: Note: see [meta discussion here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8564/should-a-new-tag-be-created-for-ftl-advanced-edition) about how to deal with FTL: AE questions with existing similar FTL questions. See also [this similar question about FTL classic](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73964/what-are-the-benefits-of-manning-a-subsystem).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sensors and Doors can now be manned to allow them to act as if they were upgraded to one level higher than their current status.

Additionally, each system also has a *fourth* power level now, only reachable by upgrading it to its max of 3 power levels and then manning the system to reach its fourth level.

- Level 3 Sensors allow you to see enemy weapons charge. (new feature)
- Level 4 Sensors allow you to see enemy power distribution (previously level 3 did this)
- Level 4 Doors give you *Super Blast Doors*. Beyond the obvious implication that these are better than *Improved Blast Doors* I'm not sure exactly what this means yet.

Comment: more info as i get it

Comment: nice, when did advanced edition come out?

Comment: @z I believe it was today.

Comment: Super blast doors get an emblemized S shape on them (not really).

Answer (score 1):

In FTL: Advanced Edition, new manning options were added. Quoting the [changelog](http://www.ftlgame.com/FTLChangeLog.html):

> **Additional manning options**: Doors and sensors can be manned to provide
>   a +1 level boost to the system. Systems redesigned to 4 levels of
>   power instead of the previous 3. Sensors at level 3 show the player
>   the cooldowns of enemy weapons, while sensors at level 4 show the
>   power bars.

Comment: Duplicating my answer from [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73964/what-are-the-benefits-of-manning-a-subsystem?lq=1) pending discussion, since I couldn't answer while this question was marked duplicate. Note: see [meta discussion here for more discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8564/should-a-new-tag-be-created-for-ftl-advanced-edition).