# How do the new door levels correspond to the old ones?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Where the original FTL: Faster Than Light had three levels of doors, the advanced edition now has four levels:

- Regular
- Blast Doors
- Improved Blast Doors
- Super Blast Doors

How do these compare to the old three-level system?  Are Improved Blast Doors a step between the previous second- and third-level doors, or are Super Blast Doors even better than the original third-level doors?

Comment: From what I can tell, but don't have proof enough to list it as an answer, the previous levels of doors are equivalent and super blast doors are stronger than anything the basic game offered.

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162866

Comment: @ChrisLee, that doesn't answer the question I'm asking.

Comment: My apologies your right, its about more about the sensors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Here FTL spanish translator answering)

**Short Answer**: YES.

**Detailed Answer**: Comparing the files "*blueprints.xml*" from FTL v1.03.3 (before Adv. Ed.) and v1.05.4 (the first Adv. Ed.), the data for 2nd. and 3rd. door levels are almost the same (changing only the upgrading price for 2nd. from 20 scraps to 35).

A new (manned and temporal) 4th. level in A.E. gives the doors more reliability containing fire and against intruders.

Comment: actually, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165494/how-do-doors-keep-fire-from-spreading says that you already won't have any fire spread with L2+ doors anyway...